# git pull thrown error in windows from git bash "index-pack failed"

Tags: git, github

Previously I can pull from this repository but recently I got this error

```
machine@bj ~/Desktop/rails-master (master)
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/rails/rails

 machine@bj ~/Desktop/rails-master (master)
 $ git pull origin master
 remote: Counting objects: 325661, done.
 remote: Compressing objects: 100% (86702/86702), done.
 effatal: early EOF  30% (97699/325661), 17.14 MiB | 861.00 KiB/s
 error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200
 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
 fatal: index-pack failed
```

I searched in google and other place but did not get any kind of suitable help

Please suggest me...
any kind of help will be appreciable....

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an error generated by Github. What happens if you try again?

Comment: same error again and again

Comment: now the error got in `35%` completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, I can clone the repo without issue:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\VonC\prog\git>git clone https://github.com/rails/rails
Cloning into 'rails'...
remote: Counting objects: 381705, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (96211/96211), done.
remote: Total 381705 (delta 293367), reused 368694 (delta 282130)
Receiving objects: 100% (381705/381705), 57.17 MiB | 587.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (293367/293367), done.
Checking out files: 100% (2715/2715), done.
```

On linux, it seems to work too, except for the very end:

```
[ VonC,vonc@laposte.net for github.com ]
Cloning into 'rails'...
remote: Counting objects: 381705, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (96211/96211), done.
remote: Total 381705 (delta 293367), reused 368694 (delta 282130)
Receiving objects: 100% (381705/381705), 57.17 MiB | 655.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (293367/293367), done.
Checking connectivity... done
error: git-remote-https died of signal 13
```

So try to:

- clone it in a new folder to check if that works better
- make sure to use the latest git version possible

Comment: I deleted the folder and again started to clone it from first...it worked thank you...

Comment: But you know I got this error again if i try to do it......sometimes I got error sometimes it works.....

Comment: @RajarshiDas what version of git are you using?

Comment: git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0

Comment: @RajarshiDas looks the right version. At least, once you have clone it, the `git pull` should work.

Comment: yes it is working....but as i say sometime i got again `index-pack failed` ..I am new on it ...so is this the problem by github or my connection?....But I am really helpful for your help thank you